# Hibernate 5.2.10 NoSuchMethodError error while execute HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am getting error like this when I call my HQL get method. I'm using Hibernate 5.2.10 version. My application server is Wildfly 10.1.0. Why I am getting this error?

```
  org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/query/Query
```

My POM.xml file has this dependency entries.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and persistence.xml has this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com_ORM_ar_0.1PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mySQL</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: in hibernate 5 you don't need a persistence.xml

Comment: i deleted persistence.xml. but error is same as before

Comment: the error itself was not because of persistence.xml. maybe you should show the code where exactly the error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your class path and remove other version hibernate jars from your class-path if any.